# How to set different consumer group id's to the same consumer factory bean in Spring boot Kafka?

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, spring-kafka

I want to use the same consumerfactory and consumerlistenercontainerfactory for different consumers. How can i add or replace more than 1 groupid in the consumerfactory?

Can someone please suggest?

Here are my consumerfactory and consumerlistenercontainerfactory beans.

```
    @Bean
    public ConsumerFactory<String, Anky> consumerFactory() {

        Map<String, Object> props = kafkaProperties.buildConsumerProperties();

        return new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(props, new StringDeserializer(),
                new JsonDeserializer<>(Anky.class, false));
    }

    @Bean
    public ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, Anky> kafkaListenerContainerFactory() {

        ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, Anky> factory = new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();
        factory.setConsumerFactory(consumerFactory());
        factory.getContainerProperties().setAckMode(AckMode.MANUAL_IMMEDIATE);
        factory.setConcurrency(3);
        return factory;
    }

**Group id is defined in the application.properties************
spring.kafka.consumer.group-id=test_consumer_group
```

I want to have multiple consumer groupids set here. Is there a way i can do it?

Answer (score 1):

You can set groupId at `@KafkaListener`

```
@KafkaListener(id = "consumer1", topics = {"topic1"}, groupId = "group1")
public void consume1(){

}

@KafkaListener(id = "consumer2", topics = {"topic2"}, groupId = "group2")
public void consume2(){

}
```

Comment: group id needs to be set in the consumerFactory bean as well... how can i add more than 1 there is my question?

Comment: Can you please tell me how are you consuming kafka logs? You can set only one group ID in consumer factory as far as I know. Tell me why do you need to set multiple group ID? Multiple groupid at the same topic will mean reading same data multiple times.

Comment: The `group.id` in the factory is simply a default, used if no `groupId` or `id` property is specified on the `@KafkaListener`. You can use `groupId = "${some.group.id}"` on the annotation if you want to set it in a property.